# How do you reindex an array in PHP but with indexes starting from 1?

Tags: php, arrays, indexing

I have the following array, which I would like to reindex so the keys are reversed (ideally starting at 1):

Current array (**edit:** the array actually looks like this):

```
Array (

[2] => Object
    (
        [title] => Section
        [linked] => 1
    )

[1] => Object
    (
        [title] => Sub-Section
        [linked] => 1
    )

[0] => Object
    (
        [title] => Sub-Sub-Section
        [linked] => 
    )

)
```

How it should be:

```
Array (

[1] => Object
    (
        [title] => Section
        [linked] => 1
    )

[2] => Object
    (
        [title] => Sub-Section
        [linked] => 1
    )

[3] => Object
    (
        [title] => Sub-Sub-Section
        [linked] => 
    )

)
```

Comment: Where is there something reversed?

Comment: See my edit to the first example

Comment: And why do you need the first element’s index being 1? Just a format matter or for internal processing?

Comment: It will be used as a param for a function to get the a url segment, something like get_url_segment(1) would return e.g. on this page "questions"

Answer (score 504, accepted):

If you want to re-index starting to zero, simply do the following:

```
$iZero = array_values($arr);
```

If you need it to start at one, then use the following:

```
$iOne = array_combine(range(1, count($arr)), array_values($arr));
```

Here are the manual pages for the functions used:

- [`array_values()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php)
- [`array_combine()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php)
- [`range()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.range.php)

Comment: You should use range(0, count($arr) - 1) so you get a zero-indexed array.

Comment: It's great, alternatively you can try using 
array_unshift($arr,'') 
to add a zero-indexed element, then unset($arr[0]) to remove it, thus moving all indexes up by one.
It maybe quicker than array_combine().  Or not :)

Comment: Note that `array_values` returns a copy of the array. So if you have references to the array then `array_splice` would be better. See @imagiro solution.

Comment: @MaxHartshorn that is not what this question is asking!

Answer (score 11):

Why reindexing? Just add 1 to the index:

```
foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
    echo $key + 1, '<br>';
}
```

---

**Edit**   After the question has been clarified: You could use the `array_values` to reset the index starting at 0. Then you could use the algorithm above if you just want printed elements to start at 1.

Answer (score 9):

You can reindex an array so the new array starts with an index of 1 like this;

```
$arr = array(
  '2' => 'red',
  '1' => 'green',
  '0' => 'blue',
);

$arr1 = array_values($arr);   // Reindex the array starting from zero*.
array_unshift($arr1, '');     // Prepend a dummy element to the start of the array.
unset($arr1[0]);              // Kill the dummy element.

print_r($arr);
print_r($arr1);
```

The output from the above is;

```
Array
(
    [2] => red
    [1] => green
    [0] => blue
)
Array
(
    [1] => red
    [2] => green
    [3] => blue
)
```

*N.B. If all the the input keys are numeric then the `array_values()` command is not needed. Since PHP 4.3 `array_unshift()` reindexes numeric keys of the the passed-in array.

Comment: @mickmackusa The `array_values()` call is necessary. It reindexes the array starting at zero.

Comment: @mickmackusa `array_unshift()` only reindexes numeric keys. But yes you are correct if all the keys are numeric, then `array_values()` is not necessary. (The question is slightly ambiguous because the question title is different to the question content.)

Answer (score 7):

This will do what you want:

```
<?php

$array = array(2 => 'a', 1 => 'b', 0 => 'c');

array_unshift($array, false); // Add to the start of the array
$array = array_values($array); // Re-number

// Remove the first index so we start at 1
$array = array_slice($array, 1, count($array), true);

print_r($array); // Array ( [1] => a [2] => b [3] => c ) 

?>
```

Answer (score 7):

You may want to consider why you want to use a 1-based array at all.  Zero-based arrays (when using non-associative arrays) are pretty standard, and if you're wanting to output to a UI, most would handle the solution by just increasing the integer upon output to the UI.

Think about consistency—both in your application and in the code you work with—when thinking about 1-based indexers for arrays.

Comment: This directly correlates to the separation between the business layer and presentation layer. If you are modifying code in your logic to accommodate presentation, you are doing bad things. For example, if you did this for a controller, suddenly your controller is tied to a specific view renderer rather preparing data for whatever view renderer it may utilize (php, json, xml, rss, etc.)

Answer (score 6):

Well, I would like to think that for whatever your end goal is, you wouldn't actually need to modify the array to be 1-based as opposed to 0-based, but could instead handle it at iteration time like Gumbo posted.

*However*, to answer your question, this function should convert any array into a 1-based version

```
function convertToOneBased( $arr )
{
    return array_combine( range( 1, count( $arr ) ), array_values( $arr ) );
}
```

### EDIT

Here's a more reusable/flexible function, should you desire it

```
$arr = array( 'a', 'b', 'c' );

echo '<pre>';
print_r( reIndexArray( $arr ) );
print_r( reIndexArray( $arr, 1 ) );
print_r( reIndexArray( $arr, 2 ) );
print_r( reIndexArray( $arr, 10 ) );
print_r( reIndexArray( $arr, -10 ) );
echo '</pre>';

function reIndexArray( $arr, $startAt=0 )
{
    return ( 0 == $startAt )
        ? array_values( $arr )
        : array_combine( range( $startAt, count( $arr ) + ( $startAt - 1 ) ), array_values( $arr ) );
}
```

Answer (score 6):

A more elegant solution:

`$list = array_combine(range(1, count($list)), array_values($list));`

Answer (score 6):

The fastest way I can think of

```
array_unshift($arr, null);
unset($arr[0]);
print_r($arr);
```

And if you just want to reindex the array(start at zero) and you have PHP +7.3 you can do it this way

```
array_unshift($arr);
```

I believe `array_unshift` is better than `array_values` as the former does not create a copy of the array.

### Changelog

| Version | Description |
| --- | --- |
| 7.3.0 | This function can now be called with only one parameter. Formerly, at least two parameters have been required. |

-- https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unshift.php#refsect1-function.array-unshift-changelog

Comment: My mistake. 
It was a flawed test.  https://3v4l.org/cetL8  `array_unshift()` with only one parameter adds nothing.

Answer (score 3):

```
$tmp = array();
foreach (array_values($array) as $key => $value) {
    $tmp[$key+1] = $value;
}
$array = $tmp;
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are not trying to reorder the array you can just do:

```
$array = array_reverse( $array );
```

and then call it once more to get it back to the same order:

```
$array = array_reverse( $array );
```

`array_reverse()` reindexes as it reverses.  Someone else showed me this a long time ago.  So I can't take credit for coming up with it.  But it is very simple and fast.

The result is an array with indexed keys starting from 0.  https://3v4l.org/iQgVh

```
array (
  0 => 
  (object) array(
     'title' => 'Section',
     'linked' => 1,
  ),
  1 => 
  (object) array(
     'title' => 'Sub-Section',
     'linked' => 1,
  ),
  2 => 
  (object) array(
     'title' => 'Sub-Sub-Section',
     'linked' => NULL,
  ),
)
```

Comment: This question is not asking for an indexed array from 0; this question is asking for sequential keys starting from 1.  This answer does not provide the desired output. https://3v4l.org/f6Pa4

Answer (score 3):

It feels like all of the `array_combine()` answers are all copying the same "mistake" (the unnecessary call of `array_values()`).

`array_combine()` ignores the keys of both parameters that it receives.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/3hEg4))

```
$array = [
    2 => (object)['title' => 'Section', 'linked' => 1],
    1 => (object)['title' => 'Sub-Section', 'linked' => 1],
    0 => (object)['title' => 'Sub-Sub-Section', 'linked' => null]
];

var_export(array_combine(range(1, count($array)), $array));
```

Output:

```
array (
  1 => 
  (object) array(
     'title' => 'Section',
     'linked' => 1,
  ),
  2 => 
  (object) array(
     'title' => 'Sub-Section',
     'linked' => 1,
  ),
  3 => 
  (object) array(
     'title' => 'Sub-Sub-Section',
     'linked' => NULL,
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my own implementation. Keys in the input array will be renumbered with incrementing keys starting from $start_index.

```
function array_reindex($array, $start_index)
{
    $array = array_values($array);
    $zeros_array = array_fill(0, $start_index, null);
    return array_slice(array_merge($zeros_array, $array), $start_index, null, true);
}
```