# How to find a value in an array and remove it by using PHP array functions?

Tags: php, arrays, function, built-in

How to find if a value exists in an array and then remove it? After removing I need the sequential index order.

Are there any PHP built-in array functions for doing this?

Answer (score 131, accepted):

To search an element in an array, you can use `array_search` function and to remove an element from an array you can use `unset` function. Ex:

```
<?php
$hackers = array ('Alan Kay', 'Peter Norvig', 'Linus Trovalds', 'Larry Page');

print_r($hackers);

// Search
$pos = array_search('Linus Trovalds', $hackers);

// array_seearch returns false if an element is not found
// so we need to do a strict check here to make sure
if ($pos !== false) {
    echo 'Linus Trovalds found at: ' . $pos;

    // Remove from array
    unset($hackers[$pos]);
}

print_r($hackers);
```

You can refer: https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php for more array related functions.

Comment: What if there is no exact match? how to perform a wildcard search?

Comment: Also note that `unset()` will turn the array into an associative array. To turn it back into an array (without keys) use [`array_values()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php)

Comment: To search by the value of a key you can combine this with `array_column`, ie: `$pos = array_search(1234, array_column('id', $dataset));`

Comment: Note: This solution will remove one value / one occurrence

Answer (score 140):

```
<?php
$my_array = array('sheldon', 'leonard', 'howard', 'penny');
$to_remove = array('howard');
$result = array_diff($my_array, $to_remove);
?>
```

Comment: Can remove multiple values without looping!

Comment: +1 avoids the tedium of checking the return value of array_search

Comment: Seems to be more efficient, the array $to_remove can be created using an array_search or preg_grep function in case if you are using wild card search to remove elements.

Comment: This solution is cleaner for me. However, note that it keeps indexes, so if you want to rearrange them in numerical order you'll want to do this: **array_values(array_diff($my_array, $to_remove))**

Comment: This should be the correct answer. If value is not found it leave's the array untouched. Thanks!

Answer (score 20):

You need to find the key of the array first, this can be done using [array_search()](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php)

Once done, use the [unset()](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php)

```
<?php
$array = array( 'apple', 'orange', 'pear' );

unset( $array[array_search( 'orange', $array )] );
?>
```

Comment: This is the result

Array ( [0] => apple [1] => orange [2] => pear [3] => green ) 
Warning: Wrong parameter count for array_search() in C:\wamp\www\test\test.php on line 5

Array ( [0] => apple [1] => orange [2] => pear [3] => green )

Comment: @learner the haystack argument was missing in http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php - the manual is your friend.

Comment: yes.
this will work 

$array = array( 'apple', 'orange', 'pear', 'green' );
unset($array[array_search('orange', $array)]);

but the array sequence is missing. How to correct that

Comment: What do you mean the sequence is missing? What sequence should it be in?

Comment: array index is 0 2 3 4 is now 1 is missing I need it like 0 1 2 4.. etc

Comment: also it has one another pbm if the search value not there array_search() function return false. it will cause the removal of 0th index value :(

Comment: Then test the value before you remove it `$key = array_search( 'value' );` And not to take the credit, but to reindex arrays, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/591094/how-do-you-reindex-an-array-in-php

Comment: But if array_search returns false because of nothing found, the first array value will be removed.

Comment: ^ I haven't verified that, but if it is true, simply do an `if ( isset( ... ) ) ` before it

Answer (score 10):

Just in case you want to use any of mentioned codes, be aware that `array_search` returns FALSE when the "needle" is not found in "haystack" and therefore these samples would unset the first (zero-indexed) item. Use this instead:

```
<?php
$haystack = Array('one', 'two', 'three');
if (($key = array_search('four', $haystack)) !== FALSE) {
  unset($haystack[$key]);
}
var_dump($haystack);
```

The above example will output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => one
    [1] => two
    [2] => three
)
```

And that's good!

Answer (score 7):

You can use [`array_filter`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) to filter out elements of an array based on a callback function. The callback function takes each element of the array as an argument and you simply return `false` if that element should be removed. This also has the benefit of removing duplicate values since it scans the entire array.

You can use it like this:

```
$myArray = array('apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'plum', 'banana');
$output = array_filter($myArray, function($value) { return $value !== 'banana'; });
// content of $output after previous line:
// $output = array('apple', 'orange', 'plum');
```

And if you want to re-index the array, you can pass the result to [`array_values`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) like this:

```
$output = array_values($output);
```

Answer (score 4):

This solution is the combination of @Peter's solution for deleting multiple occurences and @chyno solution for removing first occurence. That's it what I'm using.

```
/**
 * @param array $haystack
 * @param mixed $value
 * @param bool $only_first
 * @return array
 */
function array_remove_values(array $haystack, $needle = null, $only_first = false)
{
    if (!is_bool($only_first)) { throw new Exception("The parameter 'only_first' must have type boolean."); }
    if (empty($haystack)) { return $haystack; }

    if ($only_first) { // remove the first found value
        if (($pos = array_search($needle, $haystack)) !== false) {
            unset($haystack[$pos]);
        }
    } else { // remove all occurences of 'needle'
        $haystack = array_diff($haystack, array($needle));
    }

    return $haystack;
}
```

Also have a look here: [PHP array delete by value (not key)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7225070/php-array-delete-by-value-not-key)

Answer (score 2):

The `unset` `array_search` has some pretty terrible side effects because it can accidentally strip the first element off your array regardless of the value:

```
        // bad side effects
        $a = [0,1,2,3,4,5];
        unset($a[array_search(3, $a)]);
        unset($a[array_search(6, $a)]);
        $this->log_json($a);
        // result: [1,2,4,5]
        // what? where is 0?
        // it was removed because false is interpreted as 0

        // goodness
        $b = [0,1,2,3,4,5];
        $b = array_diff($b, [3,6]);
        $this->log_json($b);
        // result: [0,1,2,4,5]
```

If you know that the value is guaranteed to be in the array, go for it, but I think the `array_diff` is far safer. (I'm using php7)

Comment: Only if you don't do a strict comparison for `false`.  Algorhythm's and chyno's answers many years earlier do not make this mistake.

Answer (score 2):

```
$data_arr = array('hello', 'developer', 'laravel' );


// We Have to remove Value "hello" from the array
// Check if the value is exists in the array

if (array_search('hello', $data_arr ) !== false) {
     
     $key = array_search('hello', $data_arr );
     
     unset( $data_arr[$key] );
}



# output:
// It will Return unsorted Indexed array
print( $data_arr )


// To Sort Array index use this
$data_arr = array_values( $data_arr );


// Now the array key is sorted
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, as others mentioned, you will be using the "[array_search()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php)" & the "[unset()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php)" methodsas shown below:-

```
<?php
$arrayDummy = array( 'aaaa', 'bbbb', 'cccc', 'dddd', 'eeee', 'ffff', 'gggg' );
unset( $arrayDummy[array_search( 'dddd', $arrayDummy )] ); // Index 3 is getting unset here.
print_r( $arrayDummy ); // This will show the indexes as 0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6.
?>
```

Now to re-index the same array, without sorting any of the array values, you will need to use the "[array_values()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php)" method as shown below:-

```
<?php
$arrayDummy = array_values( $arrayDummy );
print_r( $arrayDummy ); // Now, you will see the indexes as 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.
?>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: But if array_search returns false because of nothing found, the first array value will be removed.

Comment: @algorhythm - Thanks for pointing that out! I will suggest that everyone should use the solution provided by you!

Comment: When you know that an answer is flawed and you leave ot on the page anyhow, you are only damaging the Researcher eXperience by confusing them with bad advice and/or wasting their time.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this is a bit longer, but does a couple of cool things.

I was trying to filter a list of emails but exclude certain domains and emails.

Script below will...

1. Remove any records with a certain domain
2. Remove any email with an exact value.

First you need an array with a list of emails and then you can add certain domains or individual email accounts to exclusion lists.

Then it will output a list of clean records at the end.

```
//list of domains to exclude
$excluded_domains = array(
    "domain1.com",
);

//list of emails to exclude
$excluded_emails = array(
    "bob@domain2.com",
    "joe@domain3.com",    
);

function get_domain($email) {

    $domain = explode("@", $email);
    $domain = $domain[1];
    return $domain;

}

//loop through list of emails
foreach($emails as $email) {

    //set false flag
    $exclude = false;

    //extract the domain from the email     
    $domain = get_domain($email);

    //check if the domain is in the exclude domains list
    if(in_array($domain, $excluded_domains)){
        $exclude = true;
    }

    //check if the domain is in the exclude emails list
    if(in_array($email, $excluded_emails)){
        $exclude = true;
    } 

    //if its not excluded add it to the final array
    if($exclude == false) {
        $clean_email_list[] = $email;
    }

    $count = $count + 1;
}

print_r($clean_email_list);
```

Comment: This different task looks like something better suited to `array_diff()`.

Answer (score -1):

To find and remove multiple instance of value in an array, i have used the below code

```
$list = array(1,3,4,1,3,1,5,8);

$new_arr=array();

foreach($list as $value){

    if($value=='1')
    {
        continue;
    }
    else
    {
        $new_arr[]=$value;
    }     
}


print_r($new_arr);
```

Comment: Why bother with the `continue` branch? Why not just push if `!= '1'`?