# Remove certain values from array in php

Tags: php, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remove empty array elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3654295/remove-empty-array-elements)

I have an array like this

```
Array ( [81] => 5.00 [78] => 4.67 [13] => 4.67 [65] => 4.60 [91] => 4.50 [4] => 4.40 [7] => 4.25 [11] => 4.20 [47] => 4.20 [21] => 4.20 [66] => 4.17 [48] => 4.00 [37] => 4.00 [69] => 4.00 [49] => 4.00 [38] => 4.00 [54] => 4.00 [62] => 4.00 [63] => 4.00 [64] => 4.00 [61] => 4.00 [60] => 4.00 [52] => 4.00 [59] => 4.00 [80] => 4.00 [50] => 4.00 [34] => 4.00 [16] => 4.00 [18] => 4.00 [9] => 4.00 [5] => 4.00 [3] => 4.00 [19] => 4.00 [20] => 4.00 [25] => 4.00 [42] => 3.83 [73] => 3.83 [28] => 3.83 [58] => 3.83 [15] => 3.83 [45] => 3.80 [10] => 3.80 [67] => 3.75 [17] => 3.75 [2] => 3.75 [27] => 3.75 [32] => 3.75 [51] => 3.75 [1] => 3.75 [31] => 3.71 [53] => 3.70 [72] => 3.70 [26] => 3.67 [82] => 3.67 [12] => 3.67 [71] => 3.67 [77] =>  [70] =>  [41] => 3.67 [8] => 3.60 [22] => 3.60 [57] => 3.60 [39] => 3.60 [83] => 3.60 [76] => 3.50 [74] => 3.50 [79] => 3.50 [43] => 3.50 [35] => 3.50 [14] => 3.50 [6] => 3.50 [44] => 3.50 [33] => 3.50 [89] => 3.33 [68] => 3.30 [29] => 3.25 [40] => 3.20 [24] => 3.17 [30] => 3.13 [56] => 3.00 [36] => 3.00 [23] => 3.00 [55] => 3.00 [46] => 2.67 [90] =>  )
```

Now what i want is to remove blank value indexes from this array. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What actually is "blank"? Provide `var_dump($arr);` instead

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7225070/php-array-delete-by-value-not-key

Comment: this might work - `$arr = array_filter($arr);`

Comment: @NiravRanpara - the selected answer, i think is broken

Comment: @Nirav Ranpara: and what would you recommend to use as a `needle`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`array_filter`](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.array-filter.php)

```
function not_empty($a)
{
    return !empty($a) && !is_null($a);
}

$array = array_filter($array, 'not_empty');
```

Comment: It's sooooooo wrong. `isset($a)` would always return `true` (in case if `$a` is, say, empty string).

Comment: @cryptic: `empty()` won't work for `' '` (which may be considered as a "blank" by OP)

Comment: @zerkms Well, it would return `true` for `null` values :)

Comment: @Jack: for `null` - yes. For `' '` - no. From my perspective the space char is a perfect candidate for "blank" ;-) (for newbie OP)

Comment: @zerkms Yeah, at this point we're all speculating what empty might entail =p

Comment: @Jack: yup, that's why I didn't even try to give my answer, though I was 1st here and had plenty of time for that ;-)

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach($array as $key => $val)
{
    if(empty($val)) unset($array[$key]);
}
print_r($array);
```

This will unset any part of the array that does not have a key

Comment: Stupid mistake, good catch!

Comment: Try again, `$key` isn't key but a value

Comment: @Vulcan: CDD - comments driven development

Comment: How about now? (This is ebarassing!)

Comment: `$array[$key]` --- what's this? `$key` isn't key, but a value

Comment: @ajreal: let's share rep points 50/50 ;-)

Comment: At this point, it's the exact same as my answer.

Comment: That's what I just noticed, Vulcan . @erkms -- isn't $key the current key of the iterated array, which would be false if unexistant?

Comment: @PRPGFerret: please look carefully through your answer modifications

Comment: Ah, I see what you did. Thank you!

Comment: @zerkms ... haha ... dun want ... you can have it all

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate through it, unsetting any empty values.

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if (empty($value)) {
        unset($array[$key]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function is_not_blank($value) {
    return $value !== false && !is_null($value) && trim($value) !== "";
}

$myArray = array_filter($myArray, "is_not_blank");
```

Comment: How about `null`s and `' '`?

Comment: @zerkms: You are right, I haven't included those - I have now modified my answer.