# Remove the element of php variable

Tags: php

i have two variable , i want remove one variable from another variable

like :

```
$var1 = '4';
$var2 = '5,7,4,9';

if ($var1 Inside $var2)
{
// remove 4
}
```

//output

```
$var2 = '5,7,9';
```

Thank you ...

Comment: is $var2 a string or an array?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) See [about Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/about).

Comment: Convert the string into an array then look if it's inside

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since it is a string, I think the easiest is to first convert it to an array, remove the value, and put it back together again:

```
$values = explode(',', $var2);

if (($key = array_search($var1, $values)) !== false) {
    unset($values[$key]);
}

$var2 = implode(',', $values);
```

The part about deleting from the array is gratefully copied from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7225113/511529).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple `str_replace` which uses regex:

```
<?php
    $var2 = str_replace("%$var1%", "", $var2); //remove the element if it is inside
    $var2 = str_replace("%,,%", ",", $var2); //Remove the ',' if it's needed
?>
```

Comment: thnx , maybe ur code is good but i found another Best solution