# get set elements from array php

Tags: php, arrays

I have array in php :

```
Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [comp_id] => 1
        [transaction_purpose] => 0
        [source_of_funds] => 1
        [beneficiary_relationship] => 0
        [cus_occupation] => 0
        [cus_id_image_2] => 0
        [cus_id_image_3] => 0
        [ben_id_type] => 0
        [ben_id_number] => 1
    )
```

I want to get only array key=>value pair if the valie is 1.

result array should be:

```
Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [comp_id] => 1
        [source_of_funds] => 1
        [ben_id_number] => 1
    )
```

I tried with:

```
$returnArray = array();
    foreach($mainArray as $r){
        if($r>0){
            array_push($returnArray, $mainArray);
        }
    }
```

But, It's giving me 4 times main array. Is there any way to achieve this? Thanks..

Comment: This looks similar to what you are asking: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7225070/php-array-delete-by-value-not-key

Comment: Look at `array_filter` anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use [`array_filter()`](https://www.php.net/array_filter):

<s>`$newarray = array_filter($array, function($var) { return ($var === 1); });`</s>

```
$newarray = array_filter($array);
```

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/gO75Sk)

```
$array = array(
    'id' => 1,
    'comp_id' => 1,
    'transaction_purpose' => 0,
    'source_of_funds' => 1,
    'beneficiary_relationship' => 0,
    'cus_occupation' => 0,
    'cus_id_image_2' => 0,
    'cus_id_image_3' => 0,
    'ben_id_type' => 0,
    'ben_id_number' => 1
);

$newarray = array_filter($array);

print_r($newarray);

Array
(
    [id] => 1
    [comp_id] => 1
    [source_of_funds] => 1
    [ben_id_number] => 1
)
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

`$returnArray = array_filter($result);`

You can see PHP's [array_filter](http://php.net/array_filter) function for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Well, what else are you expecting to happen?

```
        array_push($returnArray, $mainArray);
```

If you find an element which has >0 value, you push the **ENTIRE** original array onto the new one, not just the key/value you just tested.

You probably want:

```
$newarr = array();
foreach($mainArray as $key => $value) {
   if ($value > 0) {
        $newarr[$key] = $value;
   }
}
```