# PHP delete sub-array from multidimensional array by sub-array key value

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I've got this array:

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    ["nachricht"]=>
    string(9) "blablaaaa"
    ["user"]=>
    string(15) "334607943355808"
    ["datum"]=>
    string(16) "18.09.2014 11:13"
    ["deleted"]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
  [1]=>
  array(4) {
    ["nachricht"]=>
    string(3) "joo"
    ["user"]=>
    string(15) "334607943355808"
    ["datum"]=>
    string(16) "18.09.2014 11:56"
    ["deleted"]=>
    string(15) "334607943355808"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(4) {
    ["nachricht"]=>
    string(4) "noma"
    ["user"]=>
    string(15) "334607943355808"
    ["datum"]=>
    string(16) "18.09.2014 11:56"
    ["deleted"]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
  [3]=>
  array(4) {
    ["nachricht"]=>
    string(4) "test"
    ["user"]=>
    string(15) "334607943355808"
    ["datum"]=>
    string(16) "18.09.2014 11:56"
    ["deleted"]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
  [4]=>
  array(4) {
    ["nachricht"]=>
    string(4) "doh!"
    ["user"]=>
    string(15) "334607943355808"
    ["datum"]=>
    string(16) "18.09.2014 11:56"
    ["deleted"]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
}
```

I want to delete all sub arrays which include the value 334607943355808 in the key "deleted" in the sub array. I got this code:

```
if(($key = array_search("334607943355808", $array)) !== false) {
            unset($array[$key]);
        }
```

from: [PHP array delete by value (not key)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7225070/php-array-delete-by-value-not-key) where it's non multi-array, but how can I do it in my case?

EDIT:

I tryed it this way now:

```
foreach($array as $delete){
      if(($key = array_search("334607943355808", $delete)) !== false) {
                unset($delete[$key]);
      }
}
```

But it's not working

Comment: Use a nested foreach loop and check the values to see if they contain your number?

Comment: not as flexible, but in these case it will work just as well.

Comment: What you need is a FOREACH loop.

Comment: Look my edit, please help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just a simple `foreach` with a reference to the sub array:

```
foreach($array as &$sub_array) {
    if($sub_array['deleted'] == '334607943355808') {
        $sub_array = null;
        break; //if there will be only one then break out of loop
    }
}
```

Or by key in the main array:

```
foreach($array as $key => $sub_array) {
    if($sub_array['deleted'] == '334607943355808') {
        unset($array[$key]);
        break; //if there will be only one then break out of loop
    }
}
```

You could also extract the `deleted` values, search and unset by key:

```
if(($key = array_search('334607943355808',
                        array_column($array, 'deleted'))) !== false) {
    unset($array[$key]);
}
```

Comment: Recommend a `break;` after `unset(...)` to avoid unnecessary loops.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `array_map()`.Try this

```
$finalArr = array_map(function($v){
    if($v['deleted'] == '334607943355808') unset($v['deleted']);
    return $v;
}, $arr);
```