# Group Values of Array According to Similar Keys - PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that looks like the following:

```
$myArray = 
[
  ['email' => 'email1@email.com', 'value' => '123'],
  ['email' => 'email1@email.com', 'value' => '456'],
  ['email' => 'email1@email.com', 'value' => '789'],
  ['email' => 'email2@email2.com', 'value' => '123'],
  ['email' => 'email2@email2.com', 'value' => '456'],
  ...
]
```

What is a good way to combine the values according to unique keys (email) such that the previous array would end up like so:

```
[
  'email@email.com' => ['123', '456'],
  'email2@email2.com' => ['123', '456', '789'],
  ...
]
```

I can think of solutions, but they all seem quite inefficient :( Here is one for example:

```
$resultArray = array();
foreach ($myArray as $info) {
    if (!isset($resultArray[$info['email']])) {
        $resultArray[$info['email']] = array();
    }
    array_push($resultArray[$info['email']], $info['value']);
}
```

This doesn't sit well with me for some reason.

**QUESTION**

Are there better solutions?

-- **Updated my Blatant Mistake - Check new (1st) array :/** --

Comment: You can't have the same key twice!

Comment: Right, try `var_dump()` there will be only 2 keys.

Comment: How are you generating `$myArray`?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're getting at, @Rizier123. I don't think I do... nor do I want to...

Comment: My point is to keep only the unique keys, but aggregate their values.

Comment: @b0s3 - It is actually generated in a previous step from a SQL result. However, I am not majorly concerned about that.

Comment: @karns If you have 2 elements with the same key your array will only have 1 element

Comment: I agree with @Rizier123... It is possible same key in multidimensional array only

Comment: The above array is not possible http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30636179/how-does-php-index-associative-arrays/30636430#30636430

Comment: @Rizier123 - Please read through my question more thoroughly and let me know how I could make it clearer. I know that I can't have duplicate keys.

Comment: @Uchiha - It is indeed possible. Notice how I don't have keys that collide. I have "email..." and "email2..."

Comment: Oh! My apologies everyone, the first array is incorrect * I was thinking you were talking about the answer.. Let me update the question :/

Comment: That's  impossible [Check This](https://eval.in/378331)

Comment: @karns *I know that I can't have duplicate keys* There is your first problem. How do you want to combine all elements with the same key if they can't exist ?

Comment: @karns *the first array is incorrect* Are you serious right now?!

Comment: @Rizier123 - I am. Am I screwed in the head? It must be too early for me. What is the issue with it if they are nested arrays now?

Comment: @karns Now nothing is wrong anymore... And I look like a fool which fell for the trap. (Your code is good and works, I don't think you can write it much better than that; Besides the typo with the dollar sign in your index)

Comment: @Rizier123 - Thank you, I appreciate your patience with my ingorance :P I hope at the very least people got entertainment out of this. What do people think - should I remove this question?

Comment: @karns It's up to you, but I think you can go with this code which you already have (if you fix the dollar sign typo).

Comment: `foreach ($myArray as $item) { $newArray[$item['email']][] = $item['value']; }`. [Example here](http://ideone.com/v4WE0g).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All your checks and uses of `array_push()` can be replaced by the [empty array indexer](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.modifying). This greatly simplifies your loop as follows:

```
foreach ($myArray as $item) {
    $result[$item['email']][] = $item['value'];
}
```

An example of this is [here](http://ideone.com/v4WE0g).

Comment: Aha! I knew a more intelligent answer existed. I like it, but apparently the docs discourage it.

Comment: @karns ... you had to work hard to finally get to this answer - enjoy! And thanx again everyone for the entertainment ;-)

Comment: I think the docs are discouraging its use in fairly specific circumstances (where you don't necessarily know the underlying type of the array you're amending). In this case the entire array is constructed inside the loop, so I don't think that applies.

Comment: @cars10 - Anything to learn the language better ;) You're welcome. I think it was a result of my ignorance :D..

Comment: @Phylogenesis: I just noticed that your example host ideone.com seems to be blocked by our corporate firewall. Maybe I am not the only one?

Comment: @cars10 That's certainly possible.

Comment: Good One @Phylogenesis Cleaner Way to achieve +1

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `foreach` as

```
$myArray = 
[
  ['email' => 'email1@email.com', 'value' => '123'],
  ['email' => 'email1@email.com', 'value' => '456'],
  ['email' => 'email1@email.com', 'value' => '789'],
  ['email' => 'email2@email2.com', 'value' => '123'],
  ['email' => 'email2@email2.com', 'value' => '456'],
];
$result = array();
foreach ($myArray as $key => &$value) {
  if(isset($result[$value['email']])){
      array_push($result[$value['email']],$value['value']);
  }else{
      $result[$value['email']] = array($value['value']);
  }
}
```

[**DEMO**](https://eval.in/378347)