# array random multidimensional

Tags: php, arrays

Hi this is my array where I want to get the single dimensional array as result as shown below please help anyone

```
 Array
(
[Maruti Suzuki] => Array
    (
        [0] => Swift
        [1] => Ritz
        [2] => Omni
        [3] => New Swift DZire
        [4] => Ertiga
        [5] => Eeco
    )

[Chevrolet] => Array
    (
        [0] => Cruze
    )

)
```

This is my array I want result of this array like this

```
array(
       [Maruti Suzuki] => Swift
       [Maruti Suzuki] => Ritz
       [Maruti Suzuki] => Omini
       [Maruti Suzuki] => Eeco
       [Chevrolet] => Cruze

     )
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `call_user_func_array` as

```
$result = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $your_array);
```

**Edited :**

```
$arr = Array('Maruti Suzuki' => Array('Swift', 'Ritz', 'Omni', 'New Swift DZire', 'Ertiga', 'Eeco'), 'Chevrolet' => Array('Cruze'));
$result = array();
foreach($arr as $key => $value){
    $result[$key] = implode(',',$value);
}
```

Comment: how can get the key with the Maruti Suzuki and Chevrolet

Comment: Sorry but I think that's not your question or I'm wrong at reading it

Comment: can you please check the question again i have edited

Comment: The array that you have posted as an expected output is not possible [Reason why its not possible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30636179/how-does-php-index-associative-arrays/30636430#30636430) but you can have another option you can separate you can have comma separated array values as `array([Maruti Suzuki] => Swift,Ritz,Omini,Eeco [Chevrolet] => Cruze)` I'll add an answer for the same too

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get that

Comment: When two identical index are defined, the last overwrite the first. Means as you have posted within your expected answer it'll generate an array as `array([Maruti Suzuki] => Eeco [Chevrolet] => Cruze)`

Answer (score 0):

**edit**
To build your own new array [by hand]

```
  $result[] = $your_array['Maruti Suzuki'][0];
  $result[] = $your_array['Maruti Suzuki'][1];
  $result[] = $your_array['Maruti Suzuki'][2];
  $result[] = $your_array['Maruti Suzuki'][5];
  $result[] = $your_array['Chevrolet'][0];
```

To random your array use

```
 <?php
   $res  = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $your_array);
   $new = array_rand($res);
   $result = array();
   foreach($new as $key) $result[] = $res[$key];
```

To random your array and limit it to 5 use

```
 <?php
   $res  = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $your_array);
   $new = array_rand($res,5);
   $result = array();
   foreach($new as $key) $result[] = $res[$key];
```

In **$result** is your random new array in this case with new *keys*!

Comment: how can get the key with the Maruti Suzuki and Chevrolet

Comment: are you serious? pls update your question or your goal, if you look for another result as discriped

Comment: yes...as per the requirement your answer was satisfied....but now i have to get the keys 0-3 with the maruti suzuki and 4 with Chevrolet

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I have did what you want.

```
//sample array
$car = array
(
    'Maruti Suzuki' => array('Swift', 'Ritz', 'Omni', 'New Swift DZire', 'Ertiga', 'Eeco'),
    'Chevrolet' => array('Cruze')
);

$j = 0;
foreach ($car as $key => $value) 
{
    $count = count($value);
    for($i = 0; $i <$count;$i++)
    {
        $allCar[$key."~".$value[$i]] = $value[$i];
        $j++;   
    }
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($allCar);

?>
```

Now, you can easily get the value with the key Maruti Suzuki and Chevrolet.

Comment: its not possible to get all the value using this two index, for the same index it can swap the value of key at the end you only have two values which is  [Maruti Suzuki] => Eeco, [Chevrolet] => Cruze, if you can see my example you can easily retrieve the index as well as the vaule.