# How to set index key automatically in multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, array-merge

This is my old array.

```
$oldarray = Array
    (
        [0] => http://test.to/getac/l4p0y6ziqt9h
        [mock] => stdClass Object
            (
                [0] => http://test.to/getae/vidzichawal1
                [1] => http://test.to/getae/vidzi6
                [4] => http://test.to/getae/1x5fbr9t64xn
                [2] => http://test.to/getae/vidzi7
            )

    )
```

which i want to merge with this new array:

```
$newarray =  Array
    (
        [mock] => Array
            (
                [0] => http://test.to/getae/vidzichawal2
            )

    )
```

I am merging array by `array_merge_recursive($oldarray, $newarray);`

And the Result is this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => http://test.to/getac/l4p0y6ziqt9h
    [mock] => Array
        (
            [0] => http://test.to/getae/vidzi5
            [1] => http://test.to/getae/vidzi6
            [4] => http://test.to/getae/1x5fbr9t64xn
            [2] => http://test.to/getae/vidzi7
            [0] => http://test.to/getae/vidzichawal1
        )
);
```

All things is working good but there is one problem you can see in result there double 0 key when i am using this link in loop only 1 link retrive of 0 i want to set this keys automatically like 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 and go on after merging.

I hope you understand what i want thanks

Comment: Are you sure it has the same key twice as it is not possible?

Comment: You can't have duplicate keys!

Comment: yes i am 100% sure i have problem with this duplicate keys

Comment: after array_merge_recursive i go this duplicate keys in mock array i want to setup it like 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 ....

Comment: You can't have an array with duplicate keys [how-does-php-index-associative-arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30636179/how-does-php-index-associative-arrays/30636430#30636430)

Comment: @Uchiha i have a form where user can add link by adding link i get the newarray as u see above in question after merging it i get double 0 now how can i setup it like 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 and go on..

Comment: @Sufyan Check - https://eval.in/407926

Comment: @bos3 i am very confuse so why its give me duplicate :(

Comment: @bos3 what should i do ?

Comment: @Sufyan Can you post your original array that contains duplicate key something like image

Comment: Please provide the original data rather than the prints of the array. It may look like two  `0` zero keys but, as far as PHP is concerned, they are different but displaying as `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `array_merge()`

```
<?php
$array1 = array("color" => "red", 2, 4);
$array2 = array("a", "b", "color" => "green", "shape" => "trapezoid", 4);
$result = array_merge($array1, $array2);
print_r($result);
?>
```

The above example will output:

```
Array
(
    [color] => green
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 4
    [2] => a
    [3] => b
    [shape] => trapezoid
    [4] => 4
)
```

[REF.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)

**Note** You can't have duplicate keys!

**UPDATE**

Example using `array_merge_recursive()`

```
<?php
$oldarray = array('http://test.to/getac/l4p0y6ziqt9h', 'mock' => array('http://test.to/getae/vidzichawal1', 'http://test.to/getae/vidzi6', 'http://test.to/getae/1x5fbr9t64xn', 'http://test.to/getae/vidzi7'));
$newarray = array('mock' => array('http://test.to/getae/vidzichawal2'));

$result = array_merge_recursive($oldarray, $newarray);

var_dump($result);
?>
```

OUTPUT

```
array (size=2)
  0 => string 'http://test.to/getac/l4p0y6ziqt9h' (length=33)
  'mock' => 
    array (size=5)
      0 => string 'http://test.to/getae/vidzichawal1' (length=33)
      1 => string 'http://test.to/getae/vidzi6' (length=27)
      2 => string 'http://test.to/getae/1x5fbr9t64xn' (length=33)
      3 => string 'http://test.to/getae/vidzi7' (length=27)
      4 => string 'http://test.to/getae/vidzichawal2' (length=32)
```

Comment: @Sufyan what issue do you face while using `array_merge()`

Comment: by using array_merge all link in oldarray mock were escape and newarray mock will put in this means its not merging right its replace new with old