# create new array merge

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array:

```
array(
     [0] => Array
        (
              [d1] => Array
              (
              ................ 
              )
              [d2] => Array
              (
              ................
              )
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
              [d1] => Array
              (
              ................ 
              )
              [d2] => Array
              (
              ................
              )
        )
)
```

How to create a new array to merge it, so only d1 and d2, remove the index 0 and 1.

Comment: What did you tried so far??

Comment: It's unclear what you want to do

Comment: i wanna new array to be
     array(
                  [d1] => Array
                  (
                   ................ 
                  )
                  [d2] => Array
                  (
                   ................
                  )
            )
     )

Comment: But last one will override your all array values http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30636179/how-does-php-index-associative-arrays/30636430#30636430

Comment: Check [**this**](https://eval.in/444236) what I mean to say

Comment: how to push value..so it will be [d1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
            [1] => 1
        )

Comment: First post your attempts what you tried so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For PHP > **5.5.0** you can simply use `array_column` like as

```
$result['d1'] = call_user_func_array('array_merge',array_column($your_array,'d1'));
$result['d2'] = call_user_func_array('array_merge',array_column($your_array,'d2'));
print_r($result);
```

[**Demo**](https://3v4l.org/vEB8k)

Answer (score 0):

Let us say your array name is `$a`, so we can have:

```
$result = [];
$result['d1'] = [];
$result['d2'] = [];
foreach ($a as $v) {
    $result['d1'] = array_merge($result['d1'], $v['d1'])
    $result['d2'] = array_merge($result['d2'], $v['d2'])
}
```

Now you have what you want in `$result`.

Answer (score 0):

here is your solution [visit here](https://eval.in/444239)

Suppose your array `$menus` and after filter new array will be `$filteredMenu` . Your final result `$filteredMenu`

```
<?php 
$menus = array(
        0 =>array(
            "d1" => array (
                "id"=> "----",
                    ),
            "d2" => array (
                "id"=> "----",
                    )
            ),
         1 =>array(
             "d1" => array (
                "id"=> "----",
                    ),
            "d2" => array (
                "id"=> "----",
                    )
            )
           );

  $filteredMenu = [];
  $filteredMenu['d1'] = [];
  $filteredMenu['d2'] = [];
  foreach ($menus as $item) {
    $filteredMenu['d1'] = array_merge($filteredMenu['d1'], $item['d1']);
    $filteredMenu['d2'] = array_merge($filteredMenu['d2'], $item['d2']);
  }

 print_r($filteredMenu);
?>
```