# How do I remove all elements with a particular value from a php array? (in the shortest way possible)

Tags: php

For instance:

```
$array = ["a", "b", "c", "a", "a"];
```

I want to remove all `"a"` elements to get output:

```
$array = ["b", "c"];
```

Should also work for **ints** and **floats**.Thanks guys!

Comment: array_filter() function

Comment: Show us what you have tried? - And shortest way possible? As in speed or amount of code?

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: Shortest way in terms of amount of code.

Comment: array_unique doesn't remove all the `"a"`s

Comment: dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7225070/php-array-delete-by-value-not-key

Comment: @NicholasKajoh, Check my answer and you must be benefited...

Answer (score 0):

Use `array_diff` as defined below. You need make removed value as array and use simply the array diff to get the desired result.

```
$array = ["a", "b", "c", "a", "a"];

$arr = array_diff($array, array("a"));

print_r($arr); //Array ( [1] => b [2] => c )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, It will work for ints, floats and strings..

```
$array = [1, "b", "c", 1, "a"];

foreach (array_keys($array,1) as $key) ////array_key return matched keys
{
   unset($array[$key]); ///remove value with key
}

print_r($array);
```

This will give you :

```
Array
(
    [1] => b
    [2] => c
    [4] => a
)
```