# Wordpress show all Custom Post Type except one

Tags: wordpress, loops, custom-post-type

I am using this loop:

```
<?php
  $search_count = 0;
  $search = new WP_Query("s=$s & showposts=-1");

  if($search->have_posts()) : while($search->have_posts()) : $search->the_post();
    $search_count++;
  endwhile; endif;

  echo $search_count;
?>
```

How can I say, that I want to show every Custom Post Type, except for the post type called 'klanten' (clients in Dutch)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use like this:

```
$args = array(
    's' => $s,
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_type' => array( 'post', 'page', 'movie', 'book') // include the posts type you want to show
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Unfortunately, there's currently no way you could exclude a specific `post_type`by defining it. So, the workaround is you only define the `post_type` you want to include.

Comment: It works perfectly! To be honest, I was hoping for a way to except one post type, but this should do the trick.

Comment: Yeah. @MaartenWolfsen Unfortunately, there's currently no way you could exclude a specific `post_type`by defining it. So, the workaround is you only define the `post_type` you want to include.

Comment: A shame... ah well, maybe something for future updates

Answer (score 1):

A couple of years too late, but you can use the [get_post_types()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_types/) function with the `operator` parameter set to `not`. This way, you will receive an array of all post types except the one(s) you set in the `args` parameter of the function, which you can then use to define the `post_type` in your query:

```
$args = array(
    's' => $s,
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_type' => get_post_types(array('name' => 'klanten', 'public' => false), 'names', 'not')
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

However, you might want to `var_dump()` the result of the function first, since it will return other hidden post types you might not be interested in (like 'attachments' or others defined by plugins). This is the reason why I added `'public' => false`, which will make sure that I only receive public post types. This removes most of the undesired post types, but you should still check ('attachments' is not removed by this).

Another shortcoming of this method is that you can only remove one post type. A workaround for that would be to get all post types and then remove the ones you don't want from the array using [the method described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7225070/php-array-delete-by-value-not-key), but that seems like too much code, so in that case you might be better off just setting all the post types you want instead of the ones you don't.