# hide some category names from products in woocommerce shop

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, conditional-statements

I'd like to show some category names in the products description in my woocommerce shop page. With this code below, I'm able to show all the categories, but what I need is to **show only some category names**.

```
function wc_category_title_archive_products(){

$product_cats = wp_get_post_terms( get_the_ID(), 'product_cat' );

if ( $product_cats && ! is_wp_error ( $product_cats ) ){

    $single_cat = array_shift( $product_cats ); ?>

    <span class="categoria"><?php echo $single_cat->name; ?></span>
```

Is it possible to exclude some category names or show just the ones I need?
thank you

Comment: If you know which ones you DON'T want to show you can simply test for them and remove them from the array. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7225113/2375493) may be able to help you out.

Comment: Hope My answer was helpful to you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`WooCommerce` provides some coarse control over displaying sub categories in your shop/category pages with the “Show subcategories on category pages” and “Show subcategories on the shop page” options on the `WooCommerce > Settings > Catalog > Catalog Options` section.

These controls are all-or-nothing though: show all subcategories on the category pages, or show all subcategories on the shop page. If you want finer-grained control, for instance displaying only certain subcategories on the shop or particular subcategories on a given category catalog page, you’ll need to write a little custom code, and there are a couple of approaches you can take.

The existing limited controls, found in WooCommerce > Settings > Catalog, which allow you to hide all or none of the subcategories.

I recommend asking at https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/woocommerce#postform so the plugin’s developers and support community can help you with this.