# hide category name under products on woocommerce shop page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

This site: https://localcarbon.net/shop currently has only 2 products, making any use of categories superfluous. Therefore I do not want any category names being shown.

I have added this to the custom css:

```
/* hide category */
.product_meta {
display: none;
}
```

Which successfully removes the category name from the product page, but not the shop page. I found these in various forums and added:

```
.woocommerce-loop-category__title {
    display: none;
}
```

and:

```
.tax-product_cat .thb-shop-title {
  display: none;
}
```

But saw no effect.

I tried a couple of code snippets, but realized they were to exclude a category of products from showing, not hide the category titles.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39447458/hide-some-category-names-from-products-in-woocommerce-shop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked your website. Add this to Custom CSS to hide the categories of products on shop page:

```
a.cmsmasters_cat_color {
     display: none;
}
```

More: You can use Ctrl + Shift + C (or F12 + cursor icon) in Chrome to inspect an element. Then you can see its class that you can use to override its CSS.

I hope this helps. Have a good day.

Comment: Thanks, that did solve it, and thanks for the shortcut tip!