# Remove Woocommerce product category description on main shop page

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

I’m building my own website for a business I’m starting. I usually can find the answer online, but I’m really stuck this time.

I want to hide the category descriptions on the main woocommerce shop page that appear under the category thumbnails, but keep the descriptions on the subcategory pages.

I have managed a few PHP snippets for previous issues, but don’t really know what I’m supposed to be filling in in most cases.

I have managed to hide the product description on the subcategory page (but that’s the one I want to keep) with this code:

```
.term-description p {

display: none;

}
```

I’m guessing there’s something that needs to go before that to hide the description on the main shop page?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [hide category name under products on woocommerce shop page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57263180/hide-category-name-under-products-on-woocommerce-shop-page)

Answer (score 3):

Try this one.

```css
 .term-description {
    display: none;
}
```

If it doesn't work, please provide more code for us.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to do the same thing; after much searching I fixed it this way.

1. Install the WP plugin Simple CSS (https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-css/)
2. Go to the Product category page and then open the Customiser
3. Click the Simple CSS tab on the left menu
4. Add this CSS:

   ```
   [itemprop="description"] {
       display: none;
   }
   ```
5. Then publish.

That should solve the problem.