# Get all fields from 'pivot' table

Tags: php, eloquent, pivot, relationship, laravel-5.6

Is there a way to get all fields in the **pivot** table instead of to specify one by one?

For example (starting from the guide [here](http://laraveldaily.com/pivot-tables-and-many-to-many-relationships/)):

**shops**:

- id
- name

**products**:

- id
- name

**product_shop**:

- product_id
- shop_id
- field_1
- field_2
- field_3
- ecc...

I do not want to specify each single field:

```
public function products() {
   return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product')
        ->withPivot('field_1', 'field_2', 'field_3', 'ecc..' );
}
```

but I would return all available fields in the table; something like `->withPivot('*');`

Is there a way?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You could achieve this by first retrieving all the columns (fields) from the product_shop table and passing it as an array into the withPivot. See code below:

```
public function products() {
    $table_name = 'product_shop';

    // or you could get table name dynamically if you have a ProductShop model
    // $table_name = (new ProductShop)->getTable()

    $table_fields = Schema::getColumnListing($table_name);

    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product')
    ->withPivot($table_fields);
}
```

Don't forget to import Schema:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
```

I hope it works for you. You may want to remove some fields from the array by value. [This link explains how to remove some fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7225070/php-array-delete-by-value-not-key).

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do this because it would be quite complicated.

To prevent collisions, Laravel has to add aliases for the pivot columns:

```
`product_shop`.`field_1` as `pivot_field_1`, ...
```

So Laravel would need a list of all the columns in the pivot table. The only way to get this list is a separate query to `information_schema.columns`.

Comment: Does the answer help you?