# Is there a way to unset an element in an array by its position and not by its key value

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I have an array $old_que_ans_session which is

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [home] => https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/bmimagedump/uploads/interior/design/1533365337.jpg
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [home] => https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/bmimagedump/uploads/interior/design/1531557283.jpg
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [home] => https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/bmimagedump/uploads/interior/design/1531557681.jpg
        )

)
```

I need to unset an element in the array based on its value. For that I am doing the following to get the key

```
$key1=array_search($da1, array_column($old_que_ans_session,$da));
unset($old_que_ans_session[$key1]);

where $da = home and $old_que_ans_session is the above mentioned array. The $key1 that I am getting is 2 but there is no key value as 2 in the above mentioned array.
```

How to solve this problem.

Comment: Take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7225070/php-array-delete-by-value-not-key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`array_keys()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) to get a list of the keys and your `$key1` value to pick out the relavant key...

```
$actualKey = array_keys($old_que_ans_session)[$key1];
```

You will have to do this before you `unset()` the element in the array, otherwise the key will have gone.