# WordPress WYSIWYG Toolbars in ACF is not showing

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I need help regarding WYSIWYG editor in Advance Custom Field (ACF).

The toolbars is not showing *(e.g. bold, italic, underline... etc.)*

```
add_filter( 'acf/fields/wysiwyg/toolbars' , 'my_toolbars'  );
function my_toolbars( $toolbars )
{

    // Add a new toolbar called "Very Simple"
    // - this toolbar has only 1 row of buttons
    $toolbars['Very Simple' ] = array();
    $toolbars['Very Simple' ][1] = array('bold' , 'italic' , 'underline' );

    // Edit the "Full" toolbar and remove 'code'
    // - delet from array code from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7225070/php-array-delete-by-value-not-key
    if( ($key = array_search('code' , $toolbars['Full' ][2])) !== false )
    {
        unset( $toolbars['Full' ][2][$key] );
    }

    // remove the 'Basic' toolbar completely
    unset( $toolbars['Basic' ] );

    // return $toolbars - IMPORTANT!
    return $toolbars;
}
```

Appreciate any opinion,

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: Yes. When I click **Visual** it has an error tinymce.min.js?ver=4800-20180716:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'onpageload' of undefined.

But its all happen after I upgrade into WP 5, in the previous version is it's working perfectly.

BTW. I am using ACF 5.3.3.2

Comment: Update ACF to the latest version and install the Classic editor plugin, tell me if this helps.