# Remove key value from array

Tags: php, arrays

i am trying to remove "afterpaypayovertime" key value from the below array.
i will check for some condition & remove it based on it.
Is their any way we can do this ?

```
$paymentMethods = $paymentInformation->getPaymentMethods();
$paymentMethodsData = [];
            foreach ($paymentMethods as $paymentMethod) {
                $paymentMethodsData[] = [
                    'title' => $paymentMethod->getTitle(),
                    'code' => $paymentMethod->getCode(),
                ];
            }



// Output of $paymentMethodsData
    $paymentMethodsData = array (
          0 => 
          array (
            'title' => 'Afterpay',
            'code' => 'afterpaypayovertime',
          ),
          1 => 
          array (
            'title' => 'PayPal Credit (Paypal Express Bml)',
            'code' => 'paypal_express_bml',
          ),
          2 => 
          array (
            'title' => 'PayPal Express Checkout',
            'code' => 'paypal_express',
          ),
          3 => 
          array (
            'title' => 'Cash On Delivery',
            'code' => 'cashondelivery',
          ),
          4 => 
          array (
            'title' => 'Pay by Card (Stripe)',
            'code' => 'stripe_payments',
          ),
        );
```

Comment: I have tried these answers - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7225070/php-array-delete-by-value-not-key
but did not work for me.

Comment: That question is about 1-dimensional arrays, not 2-dimensional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do it

```
$deleteKey = false;
foreach($array as $key => $value) {
    if($value['code'] === 'afterpaypayovertime') {
        $deleteKey = $key;
        break;
    }
}

if($deleteKey !== false) unset($array[$deleteKey]);
```

Comment: `foreach ($array as $key => $value)`

Comment: This won't work if `$key == 0` since that's falsey.

Comment: @Barmar, yep, you are right. Applied edits