# How to remove NaN from array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, nan, rrdtool, rrd

How do I remove NaN values from an array in php?

```
$array = [1, 3, 5, 3, float(NaN), 4, float(NaN)];
$desired_result = [1, 3, 5, 3, 4];
```

To remove any other element, I found this solution, but I can't get it to work for NaN.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7225113/9606753

Context: I am reading data from an rrd Database. I want to calculate the mean across several data entries, however at least one of them is float(NaN).

Comment: Use the `$strict` parameter of `array_search`.

Comment: `float(NaN)` is not a valid PHP code (`NAN` should be used). And `NAN` is already a float.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [array_filter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) to remove NaN with [is_nan](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-nan.php) function.

```php
$array = [1, 3, 5, 3, float(NaN), 4, float(NaN)];
$filtered_array = array_filter($array, function ($element) {
    return !is_nan($element);
});
```

<s>**Note:** This will also remove numbers that are stored as strings, '21' for example would be removed.</s>

Comment: How could I modify this to keep string numbers?

Comment: [is_numeric](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php) might be better, especially since `float(NaN)` is not a valid PHP structure, and is most likely a string coming from the DB anyway

Comment: is_numeric returns true when passing NaN to it. `var_dump(is_numeric(sqrt(-1)));`

Comment: For me, it keeps numbers stored as string. This is a perfect solution to me. Thank you!  ```<?php
$array = [1, 3, 5, "5", acos(2)];
$filtered_array = array_filter($array, function ($element) {
    return !is_nan($element);
});

var_dump($filtered_array);
?>```