# how do i unset multiple keys in php

Tags: php, arrays, unset

I am getting error while unset the data. Can anyone tell me how to do that. Here i have column array look like:-

```
enter code here
Array
(
[0] => Id
[1] => Name
[2] => MainDeity
[3] => Description
[4] => MainImage
[5] => Category
[6] => Tehsil
[7] => City
[8] => District
[9] => State
[10] => Terrain
```

)
I am using laravel framework i want to unset three columns Id,State,Terrain
I have used this code but it shows me error:- **Cannot unset string offsets**

```
enter code here
 $columns = Schema::getColumnListing('places');
    foreach ($columns as $key => $value) {
        if($value=="Id"){
            unset($value[$key]);
        }
        $columndata[] = $value;
    }

    echo "<pre>";print_r($columndata); die;
```

Comment: you want to unset keys by checking its values ? correct ?

Comment: yes i want to unset by its value

Comment: check this once http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059392/how-to-find-a-value-in-array-and-remove-it-by-using-php-array-functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this code,

```
$arr = ["0" => "Id", "1" => "Name"
    ];
    $columndata = [];
 foreach ($arr as $key => &$value) {
    if(in_array($value,["Id",'State','Terrain']){
        unset($value);
    }else{
     $columndata[] = $value;
    }
}
$columndata = array_values(array_filter($columndata));
print_r($columndata);
```

Error was coming because, after check id, you are unsetting that value. And then trying to save that value in columndata.

Here is working [code](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/dfff98af146084ba2c67cdb9e285330be2545138)

Answer (score 3):

This is an easy one-liner:

```
$result = array_diff(Schema::getColumnListing('places'), ['Id', 'State', 'Terrain']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be like this,

```
 $columns = Schema::getColumnListing('places');
    foreach ($columns as $key => $value) {

        if($value=="Id"){
            unset($columns[$key]);
        } else {
            $columndata[] = $value;
        }   

    }

    echo "<pre>";print_r($columndata); die;
```

Comment: i think when i print columnsarray it will run fine