# PHP reindex array?

Tags: php, arrays, indexing

I have array that i had to unset some indexes so now it looks like

```
$myarray [0] a->1
         [1] a-7 b->3
         [3] a-8 b->6
         [4] a-3 b->2
```

as you can see [2] is missing all i need to do is reset indexes so they show [0]-[3].

Comment: This is most definitely not a duplicate of [**How do you reindex an array in PHP?**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/591094/how-do-you-reindex-an-array-in-php)  Sharing a solution does not establish duplicity.

Answer (score 369, accepted):

Use [`array_values`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php).

```
$myarray = array_values($myarray);
```

Answer (score 115):

```
$myarray = array_values($myarray);
```

[array_values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php)

Answer (score 21):

array_values does the job :

```
$myArray  = array_values($myArray);
```

Also some other php function do not preserve the keys, i.e. reset the index.

Answer (score 1):

This might not be the simplest answer as compared to using array_values().

Try this

```
$array = array( 0 => 'string1', 2 => 'string2', 4 => 'string3', 5 => 'string4');
$arrays =$array;
print_r($array);
$array=array();
$i=0;
    foreach($arrays as $k => $item)
    {
    $array[$i]=$item;
        unset($arrays[$k]);
        $i++;

    }

print_r($array);
```

[Demo](http://3v4l.org/unrGQ)