# Assigning New array keys

Tags: php, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP reindex array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7558022/php-reindex-array)

Is there a specific PHP function to assign new ordered keys to an array?

I have an array as follows:

```
array(
 0 =>'abc',
 2 =>'pqr',
 3 =>'xyz'
)
```

I want a new array out of this as follows:

```
array(
     0 =>'abc',
     1 =>'pqr',
     2 =>'xyz'
    )
```

Is there a PHP built-in function for this? I know I can do this with `foreach`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will do the trick:

```
$aNew = array_values($aOld);
```

Comment: Thanx wesley..i didnt noticed that before