# How to move the keys of array to the top in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have got an array

```
$array = array(
0=>'c'
1=>'a',
2=>'b',
3=>'d',
);
```

Now, i am going to unset the 1 and 2 keys.

```
unset($array[1]); unset($array[2]);
```

How to do if i want an array

```
array(0=>'c', 1=>'d');
```

Comment: Use `$array = array_values($array);`. And searchbar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This:

$array = array_values($array);

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
unset($array[1]);
unset($array[2]);
$array = array_values($array);
```

This works because array_values returns the array you gave, but with increasing keys starting at 0.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tired to use something like that ?

```
$myarray [0] a->1
         [1] a-7 b->3
         [3] a-8 b->6
         [4] a-3 b->2

array_values

$myarray = array_values($myarray);
```

btw here is a good [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7558022/php-reindex-array) posted