# adjust keys in an array

Tags: php, arrays, key

For example I have the following array :

```
$arr[0] = "1"
$arr[7] = "p"
$arr[10] = "c"
$arr[12] = 'k"
```

How do I transform it to :

```
$arr[0] = "1"
$arr[1] = "p"
$arr[2] = "c"
$arr[3] = 'k"
```

Comment: use the [array_values()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) function

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP reindex array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7558022/php-reindex-array)

Comment: Your quotes are missmatching in the example :O

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
$arr = array_values($arr);
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php