# Renaming values in multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array that currently looks similar to this:

```
Array 
(
    [0] => Array 
        (
        [name] => Mike
        [date] => 2014
        )
    [1] => Array 
        (
        [name] => Jason
        [date] => 2011
        )
    [4] => Array 
        (
        [name] => Dan
        [date] => 2009
        )
    [8] => Array 
        (
        [name] => Jeff
        [date] => 2012
        )
)
```

Using php, How do I rename the numbers so they read consecutively, like so?… [0][1][2][3] instead of [0][1][4][8]

Comment: How is the array generated? Is it not possible to set them there? If not, try looking at this page: http://www.php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php (I simply searched Google for "PHP array sort" - Who'd have thought..)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just do `$array = array_values($array);` as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7558041/2765666).

Comment: Thank you George. I am new to php and without a proper education it is difficult for me to teach myself the basics to allow me to navigate this abstract space. I really appreciate the efforts of people like you on Stack Overflow.