# How can I re-update value in the array if the key deleted on the php?

Tags: php, arrays

My code to delete key like this :

```
<?php
    $photoList = array(
        array(
            'id' => 1,
            'name' => 'chelsea.jpg'
        ),
        array(
            'id' => 2,
            'name' => 'mu.jpg'
        ),
        array(
            'id' => 3,
            'name' => 'city.jpg'
        )
    );
    if(count($photoList) > 1) {
        $id = 1;
        foreach($photoList as $key => $value) {
            if($value['id'] == $id)
                unset($photoList[$key]);   
        }
    }
    echo '<pre>';print_r($photoList);echo '</pre>';
?>
```

If the code executed, the result like this :

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => mu.jpg
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [name] => city.jpg
        )
)
```

I want the value re-update. So id start from 1 and the key start from 0 like this :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => mu.jpg
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => city.jpg
        )
)
```

How can I do it?
Please help me, what is wrong? thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP reindex array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7558022/php-reindex-array)

Comment: As I see there is nothing wrong,you have no code at all that does what you want.

Comment: @NguyenThanh It just key. I want to re-update the id too. So the id start from 1. Please see my question well. My question is not duplicate

Comment: @NguyenThanh notice that OP wants to change the values to, not only the keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can keep a flag `$delete` and use that to remember if a delete has been done and then change the values if it's true.

```
if(count($photoList) > 1) {
    $id = 1;
    $delete = false;
    foreach($photoList as $key => &$value) { // notice the & to make it by reference (editable)
        if($value['id'] == $id && $delete == false){
            $delete = true;
            unset($photoList[$key]);   
        }Else if($delete == true){
            $value["id"] = $id;
            $id++; // update id for next value in array
        }
    }
}
$photoList= array_values($photoList);
```

https://3v4l.org/N2qjm

---

Without reference:

```
if(count($photoList) > 1) {
    $id = 1;
    $delete = false;
    foreach($photoList as $key => $value) {
        if($value['id'] == $id && $delete == false){
            $delete = true;
            unset($photoList[$key]);   
        }Else if($delete == true){
            $photoList[$key]["id"] = $id;
            $id++;
        }
    }
}
$photoList= array_values($photoList);
```

Comment: May I remove the mark `&` in the `foreach($photoList as $key => &$value) {`. Seem in my case the mark `&` is problematic. I can not explain to you. Because it will be long. So I need you remove mark `&` only.

Comment: If I remove the & the code won't work. The & means we can edit the values in $photolist from $value. You can of course reference to the photlist instead of value, but not sure why this is a problem for you. I will update the code with a non referenced code.

Comment: I use laravel framework. If I use referenced code, it's problematic. But thanks. Your update code works

Comment: Maybe it's that you need to unset the value after the foreach? I have never encountered the problem myself, but some say you should always unset referenced values after the foreach. `unset($value);`

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```
   <?php
            $photoList = array(
                array(
                    'id' => 1,
                    'name' => 'chelsea.jpg'
                ),
                array(
                    'id' => 2,
                    'name' => 'mu.jpg'
                ),
                array(
                    'id' => 3,
                    'name' => 'city.jpg'
                )
            );
            $newphotolist = [];
            $counter_id = 0;
            if(count($photoList) > 1) {
                $id = 1;
                foreach($photoList as $key => $value) {
                    if($value['id'] != $id){
                        $counter_id++;
                        $arr = array('id' => $counter_id, 'name' => $value['name']);
                        $newphotolist[] = $arr;
                    }
                }
            }
            echo '<pre>';print_r($newphotoList);echo '</pre>';
        ?>
```

Comment: An answer should always include a description of what it does.

Answer (score 0):

```
$photoList = array(
        array(
            'id' => 1,
            'name' => 'chelsea.jpg'
        ),
        array(
            'id' => 2,
            'name' => 'mu.jpg'
        ),
        array(
            'id' => 3,
            'name' => 'city.jpg'
        )
    );
    if(count($photoList) > 1) {
        $id = 1;
        foreach($photoList as $key => $value) {
            if($value['id'] == $id)
                unset($photoList[$key]);   
        }
    }
```

at the end of your job, reorder your key first.

```
$photoList = array_values($photolist);
```

and then, reorder your id.

```
foreach($photoList as $key=>$val) {
    $photoList[$key]['id'] = $key+1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`<?php
    $photoList = array(
        array(
            'id' => 1,
            'name' => 'chelsea.jpg'
        ),
        array(
            'id' => 2,
            'name' => 'mu.jpg'
        ),
        array(
            'id' => 3,
            'name' => 'city.jpg'
        )
    );
    if(count($photoList) > 1) {
        $id = 1; $intStartId = 1;
        foreach($photoList as $key => &$value) {
            if($value['id'] == $id)
                unset($photoList[$key]);

            else {
                $value['id'] = $intStartId;
                ++ $intStartId;
            }
        }
    }
    $photoList = array_merge(array(), $photoList);
    echo '<pre>';print_r($photoList);echo '</pre>';`