# Move array item with certain key to the first position in an array, PHP

Tags: php, arrays

What's the most elegant way in PHP to move an array element chosen by key to the first position?

Input:

```
$arr[0]=0;
$arr[1]=1;
$arr[2]=2;
....
$arr[n]=n;
$key=10;
```

Output:

```
$arr[0]=10;
$arr[1]=0;
$arr[2]=1;
$arr[3]=2;
....
$arr[n]=n;
```

Comment: In the example, you're not "choosing element by key". You're just inserting an arbitrary value to the beginning of the array. I think this might confuse other people

Comment: @galymzhan I think it's implied that $arr[10] was previously 10, and now it goes from $arr[9]=9 to $arr[10]=11. I agree that the example doesn't illustrate this clearly. It would be better to a) show the array element that's being "moved", and b) use different element values so it's harder to confuse a key with its value.

Comment: It seems the best will be the good old way with a temporary array and cycle

Comment: @octern Yes, I think you're right, because size of `$arr` remains the same `$arr[n] = n`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No need to unset keys. To keep it short just do as follow

```
//appending $new in our array 
array_unshift($arr, $new);
//now make it unique.
$final = array_unique($arr);
```

**[Demo](http://phpfiddle.org/lite?code=%3C?php%5Cn$arr%20=%20array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,3,10);%5Cnvar_dump($arr);%5Cnecho%20'%3Cbr%3E';%5Cn$new%20=%20intval('3');%5Cnarray_unshift($arr,%20$new);%5Cnvar_dump(array_unique($arr));%5Cn?%3E%5Cn)**

Comment: This solution works only for arrays containing numbers and ignoring it's key. Also, it's inserting a new element, but the question asks how to move an existent array item to the first position. It clearly doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 40):

Use [`array_unshift`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unshift.php):

```
$new_value = $arr[n];
unset($arr[n]);
array_unshift($arr, $new_value);
```

Comment: The same array, it looks as if it doesn't change keys

Comment: oops edit: I was printing out keys, let me try once more. Of course it works. I'm sorry for the confusion

Comment: Glad it helped. Notice that the array needs to be reindexed afterwards. Read here how to do this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/591094/how-do-you-reindex-an-array-in-php

Answer (score 16):

Old question, and already answered, but if you have an associative array you can use array_merge.

```
$arr = array_merge([$key=>$arr[$key]], $arr);
```

---

EDITED (above to show PHP7+ notation, below is example)

```
$arr = ["a"=>"a", "b"=>"b", "c"=>"c", "d"=>"d"];
$arr = array_merge(["c"=>$arr["c"]], $arr);
```

The effective outcome of this operation

```
$arr == ["c"=>"c", "a"=>"a", "b"=>"b", "d"=>"d"]
```

Comment: Doesn't this code **copy** the element instead of **moving** it?

Comment: @Gonzalingui, You may be right! Doesn't it depends on the value in the array, though? If it is scalar, it might copy it but if it is a reference value then wouldn't it only copy the reference and not the value?

(I could be wrong, but I don't think the OP was asking more about changing the value in an array variable than the underlying computer science fundamentals of moving versus copying a value in held in memory. :) )

Answer (score 7):

Something like this should work. Check if the array key exists, get its value, then `unset` it, then use `array_unshift` to create the item again and place it at the beginning.

```
if(in_array($key, $arr)) {
    $value = $arr[$key];
    unset($arr[$key]);
    array_unshift($arr, $value);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
<?php
$key = 10;
$arr = array(0,1,2,3);
array_unshift($arr,$key);
var_dump($arr) //10,0,1,2,3
?>
```

Comment: This prepends the chosen element, but it doesn't reference it by key and remove it from elsewhere in the array.

Answer (score 4):

Since any numeric key would be re-indexed with `array_unshift` (as noted [in the doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unshift.php)), it's better to use the `+` array union operator to move an item with a certain key at the first position of an array:

```
$item = $arr[$key];
unset($arr[$key]);
$arr = array($key => $item) + $arr;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$arr[0]=0;
$arr[1]=1;
$arr[2]=2;
$arr[3]=10;


$tgt = 10;
$key = array_search($tgt, $arr);
unset($arr[$key]);
array_unshift($arr, $tgt);

// var_dump( $arr );
array
0 => int 10
1 => int 0
2 => int 1
3 => int 2
```

Answer (score 1):

For example, so: `$arr = [$key => $arr[$key]] + $arr;`

Answer (score 1):

if you have numeric keys they will be re-indexed starting from 0 if you ***array_merge*** them.
To avoid it use **+** operator:

```
[2 => 'blue'] 
+
[31 =>  'red',
 2 =>  'blue',
 254 =>  'black'];
```

this will give

```
[2 =>  'blue',
 31 =>  'red',
 254 =>  'black']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$tgt = 10;
$key = array_search($tgt, $arr);
for($i=0;$i<$key;$i++)
{
   $temp = $arr[$i];
   $arr[$i] = $tgt;
   $tgt = $temp;
}
```

After this simple code, all you need to do is display the re-arranged array. :)