# Move an element to first position in an array

Tags: php, arrays

here is my array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 8
            [title] => MUSIC
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 17
            [title] => Indie
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 14
            [title] => SPORTS
        )

    [3] => Array         // Need to move this on first position
        (
            [id] => 15
            [title] => Hipster  
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 16
            [title] => Web Seriesdf
        )
   )
```

I want array with key [3] to be on first position and then the rest of the elements. 
I tried array_merge and array_unshift. But not working

Comment: Is your array guaranteed to be numerically indexed? Do you care about preserving the numeric indexing after moving the element?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Move array item with certain key to the first position in an array, PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11703729/move-array-item-with-certain-key-to-the-first-position-in-an-array-php)

Comment: It would be good if you could mark some answer as correct.

Answer (score 6):

You just need to take only three steps.
- Copy **n'th** array in variable.
- Delete **n'th** index from array. using [unset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php)
- Put **variable** at the **0th index** of the array. Using [array_unshift()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unshift.php)

**Step 1:**

```
$array=$mainArray[N];
```

**Step 2:**

```
unset($mainArray[N]);
```

**Step 3:**

```
array_unshift($mainArray, $array);
```

Answer (score 3):

Lets assume your array to be $x;

```
$new_value = $x[3];
unset($x[3]);
array_unshift($x,$new_value);
```

This shall solve your problem.

Comment: @AniketPandya hahaha don't be greedy you have 4 votes up already `:-p` ,

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11703729/move-array-item-with-certain-key-to-the-first-position-in-an-array-php

Comment: Not sure why you deleted your previous answer that was identical to this one? Perhaps because it had a comment similar to Adbulla's saying it was copy pasted?

Answer (score 2):

You can also use array_merge

```
<?php
$a = [1,2,3,4,5];
$new_value = [$a[1]];
unset($a[1]);
$c = array_merge($new_value,$a);
print_r($c);
```

?>

Check output : https://eval.in/590702

Comment: while this is a nice alternative to `array_unshift`, could you explain about how this works?

Answer (score 2):

**Use**

```
$array = array('3' => $array['3']) + $array;
```

[phpfiddle Preview](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/dj4m-530r) and [eval.in Preview](https://eval.in/590709)

> **Note: im moving 2 in my array. In your method add 3**

---

**Example**

```
$array = array(
    '0' => array(
        'id'=>'8',
        'title'=>'MUSIC'
        ),
    '1'     => array(
        'id'=> '17',
        'title'=> 'Indie'
        ),
     '2'     => array(
        'id'=>'14',
        'title'=>'SPORTS',
        ),
     '3'     => array(
        'id'=>'14',
        'title'=>'SPORTS',
        ),
    );

$array = array('2' => $array['2']) + $array;
print_r($array);
```

**Output**

```
Array ( [2] => Array ( [id] => 14 [title] => SPORTS ) [0] => Array ( [id] => 8 [title] => MUSIC ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 17 [title] => Indie ) [3] => Array ( [id] => 14 [title] => SPORTS ) )
```

Answer (score 1):

Use array_unshift();

Please check below code.

```
<?php
$a = Array(
    '0' => Array('id' => '8','title' => 'MUSIC'),
    '1' => Array('id' => '17','title' => 'Indie'),
    '2' => Array('id' => '14','title' => 'SPORTS'),
    '3' => Array('id' => '15','title' => 'Hipster'),
    '4' => Array('id' => '16','title' => 'Web Seriesdf')
   );
echo '<pre>';print_r($a); 
$a3 = $a['3'];
unset($a['3']);
array_unshift($a,$a3);
echo '<pre>';print_r($a);   
?>
```

Check output - https://eval.in/590723