# Moving array element to beginning of array?

Tags: php, html, arrays

If I have an array like the one below how would I go about moving key [2] and its associated value to the beginning of the array ? (making it key [0] and increasing the other keys by 1)

Current:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [name] => Vanilla Coke cans 355ml x 24
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [name] => Big Red Soda x 24
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [name] => Reeses White PB Cups - 24 CT
    )
```

Desired outcome:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [name] => Reeses White PB Cups - 24 CT
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [name] => Vanilla Coke cans 355ml x 24
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [name] => Big Red Soda x 24
    )
```

**EDIT**

To clarify I do will always want to move an element to the begining of the array but it wont necessarily be the last element it can sometimes be the 3rd 4th e.c.t. it varies each time.

Comment: Have you searched online for a solution? https://stackoverflow.com/a/11703775/630203

Comment: I did see array_unshift however I thought it simply added a value not moved it ?

Comment: "The array_unshift() function inserts new elements to an array. The new array values will be inserted in the beginning of the array" - this is nearly what I want however I was hoping there was a simpler solution other than using array_unshift and then removing the duplicate value.

Comment: Thank you thats a good point I wasnt very clear, I apologize for that, I have edited the post, and its not always the last element the element I want to move to the beginning each time varies in position however it does always need to be added to the beginning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`array_splice` removes (and optionally replaces / inserts) values from an array returning an array with the removed items. In conjunction with the simple `array_unshift` function the job could be done.

```
$arr = [1,2,3,4,5];

function array_move_item_as_first(array $array, int $idx) : array
{
  array_unshift( $array, array_splice($array, $idx, 1)[0] );
  return $array;
}

print_r(array_move_item_as_first($arr, 2));
```

**output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 3
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 2
    [3] => 4
    [4] => 5
)
```

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use `array_unshift` and `array_pop` together?

```
array_unshift($someArray, array_pop($someArray));
```

[array_pop](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php) removes the last element, and [array_shift](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unshift.php) prepends the entry to the array.