# Access array by its numeric index

Tags: php

I have this array

```
Array ( [name] => guardian [url] => http://www.guardian.co.uk )
Array ( [name] => cnn [url] => http://www.cnn.com )
```

which i am accessing like

```
$das_repeat = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'repeatable_fields', true);
    foreach ( $das_repeat as $fiel ) {
    echo $fiel['name'].'<br/>';
    //print_r($fiel);
    }
```

However, i am very interested in accessing each value by its numeric index.How can i reindex `$fiel['name']` to allow me access each value by its index?.

Comment: use `$das_repeat=array_values($das_repeat);` then foreach or get values by numeric index

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/591224/1438393

Comment: Do you have one array or multiple arrays? Or is it nested arrays and yo didn't show the outer level?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your array does not have numeric indices, it does not really make sense to access it by numeric indices. You can strip all the keys out and reindex the array numerically:

```
$reindexed = array_values($das_repeat);
```

However, again, it doesn't really make sense to do so. If you want to iterate over the array without knowing its keys, you're already doing that using `foreach`.

Answer (score 1):

To re-index an array you can use [`array_values`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php).

```
$array = array(
    'name' => 'A name',
    'attr2' => 'Attr 2'
);
$array = array_values($array);
var_dump($array);
```

**Result:**

```
array
  0 => string 'A name' (length = 6)
  1 => string 'Attr 2' (length = 6)
```

Although, as @deceze pointed out, this has the potential to cause bugs and/or unexpected behavior in your code, so use wisely. For example, think about what will happen if, for some reason, the 1st post meta will be deleted. All the information you show will be wrong.

**Note: Is not recursive**

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ( $das_repeat as $id => $fiel ) {
    echo $fiel['name'].'<br/>';
    //print_r($fiel);
    // $id not contains the index
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [array_values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php).

```
foreach ( $das_repeat as $fiel ) {
    $field = array_values($fiel);
    echo $field[0]; //will output guardian and then cnn
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As other answers say, you can use `array_values` to create a new array with the same values, but numeric indices. If you want to keep the associative array as it is, but *also* access it numerically, you could do this:

```
$keys = array_keys($das_repeat);
$elementN = $das_repeat[$keys[$N]];
```