# Convert 0-based array to 1-based

Tags: php, arrays

I have a 0-based array

```
$days = ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun'];
```

I'd like to have it start at index one:

```
$days = [1 => 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun'];
```

How could I do that, cleanest?

I have this but it's a bit ugly imo:

```
array_unshift($days, null);
unset($days[0]);
```

Comment: Better: http://stackoverflow.com/a/591224/3933332 ?!

Comment: Why do you need to change the index number? The code that uses this array should be accounting for the index offset, not the array itself.

Comment: The code will can be much cleaner if it doesn't need to offset the indexes

Comment: @Rizier123 The unshift way tends to be quite a bit faster: http://3v4l.org/I5BT4

Comment: @MightyPork Also, how is the array initially constructed?

Comment: I get it from a framework, it contains the localized day names. Indexes are 0..6

Comment: I'm just fishing for a possible cleaner solution, if there's none I'll keep my unshift ..

Comment: FYI: micro-optimizing array operations on arrays with less than several thousand entries is generally pointless. Do whatever is more readable (developer time > execution time).

Answer (score 2):

The cleanest way to do this (with regards to dates) is to literally just use indexes directly.

Since you're refusing to use normal zero-based indexes, making a zero-based index and then incrementing all indexes would just be a bunch of magic that could very easily harm readability.

Literally, just do this:

```
$days = [
    1 => 'Mon',
    2 => 'Tue',
    3 => 'Wed',
    4 => 'Thu',
    5 => 'Fri',
    6 => 'Sat',
    7 => 'Sun',
];
```

Your intent is then crystal clear, and people wont be wondering what funky voodoo you did to a zero-indexed array.

Failing that, if you really have to, you can generate an array of values equal to the length of `$days` and use `array_combine`

```
$days = ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun'];
$keys = range(1, count($days));
$new = array_combine($keys, $days);
```

Comment: I don't think OP is necessarily 'refusing' to use zero-based indices.  One major reason that comes to mind where they *must* use 1-based indices is if they are using PDO.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays are 0 based by default.

$days = ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun'];

Probably you need to change your array to an map key-value

```
// Original array
$days = array('Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun');

// Keys for the array
$keys = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7);
$days = array_combine($keys, $days);

// Print the new array with keys
print_r($days);

// Access to array $days[1] ...
```

Result:

```
 Array ( [1] => Mon [2] => Tue [3] => Wed [4] => Thu [5] => Fri [6] => Sat [7] => Sun )
```

If the array is static in your code you could do this directly:

```
$days = array(1=>'Mon', 2=>'Tue', 3=>'Wed', 4=>'Thu', 5=>'Fri', 6=>'Sat', 7=>'Sun');
```

Also is possible to use the array with zero index based using the $index that is required minus 1

```
$value = $days[ ($index -1 )];
```