# How remove and reindex arrays duplicate by comparing multiple values in php?

Tags: php

How **remove** and **reindex** arrays duplicate **by comparing spécific values** source and target?

Sample array to process:

```
Array
(
    [links] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [source] => galaxy
                    [target] => s7
                    [value] => 1
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [source] => galaxy
                    [target] => s7
                    [value] => 1
                )           
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [source] => s7
                    [target] => galaxy
                    [value] => 1
                )
            [3] => Array
                (
                    [source] => galaxy
                    [target] => s8
                    [value] => 1
                )
        )
)
```

Desired result:

```
Array
(
    [links] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [source] => galaxy
                    [target] => s7
                    [value] => 1
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [source] => s7
                    [target] => galaxy
                    [value] => 1
                )               
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [source] => galaxy
                    [target] => s8
                    [value] => 1
                )
        )
)
```

Thank's

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove duplicate values from a multi-dimensional array in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307674/how-to-remove-duplicate-values-from-a-multi-dimensional-array-in-php)

Comment: @ficuscr please, take the time to read the question carefully, cordially.

Comment: I almost feel like this is rhetorical anyway... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/591094/how-do-you-reindex-an-array-in-php/6507615#6507615

Comment: @ficuscr it's not the same question because the need is different. Please, stay friendly. cordiality

Comment: Always. If it's not a dupe it's not a dupe. I'm just failing to understand you obviously. I'll leave the link and retract the close vote. Nothing personal. Happy Friday.

Comment: When you say "comparing specific values source and target" does that mean that the value key may have different values for the same source and target? If that's the case, which value should be kept? And if that's not the case, can you explain a bit more how this is different than the suggested duplicate?

Answer (score 2):

Are you saying the linked answer does not work because of the "reindex" aspect? I did read carefully I thought. Since you shared no code maybe elaborate a bit if I am still missing something?

Here:

```
 <?php
 $foo = [
   ['source' => 'g', 'target' => 's7'],
   ['source' => 'g', 'target' => 's7'],
   ['source' => 's7', 'target' => 'g'],
   ['source' => 'g', 'target' => 's8']
];

var_dump(array_values(array_unique($foo, SORT_REGULAR)));
```

> ```
> array(3) {
>   [0]=>
>   array(2) {
>     ["source"]=>
>     string(1) "g"
>     ["target"]=>
>     string(2) "s7"
>   }
>   [1]=>
>   array(2) {
>     ["source"]=>
>     string(2) "s7"
>     ["target"]=>
>     string(1) "g"
>   }
>   [2]=>
>   array(2) {
>     ["source"]=>
>     string(1) "g"
>     ["target"]=>
>     string(2) "s8"
>   }
> }
> ```

Comment: Same here, looks reasonable to me. Too many question marks maybe? ;)